# c# winforms webbrowser control - how to download an image?

Tags: c#, image, browser

In a Winforms app I have a webbrowser control that is logged in to a site.
Now I want to download an image (that can only be downloaded when logged in to that site) programmatically.

So how do I tell my webbrowser control to download an image, ie. http://www.example.com/image.jpg, and save it somewhere ?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to save the file directly to your hard drive, you can download it into a stream.  e.g.

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
byte[] bytes = wc.DownloadData("http://www.example.com/image.jpg");
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(new MemoryStream(bytes));
```

If you then wish to save it to your hard drive, you can call the `Bitmap.Save()` method. e.g.

```
b.Save("bitmap.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can't do that silently using a WebBrowser. Don't forget that it's an IE instance at the end. What you can do is: Navigate to the ImageURL, then Invoke ShowSaveAsDialog() that will show a Save as dialog to the user to save the Image:

```
WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowseR();
wb.Navigate("ImageURL");
wb.ShowSaveAsDialog();
```

A better solution is to get the Image using a WebClient

```
System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
wc.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password"); //Authenticates to the website - Call it only if the image url needs authentication first
wc.DownloadFile("imageURL", "downloadedImage.jpg"); //Downloads the imageURL to the local file downloadedImage.jpg
```